# Different WYSIWYG editors for each user?

Tags: editor

Title says it all, is it possible to have a different editor for each user within Joomla?

For example,

User 1 uses the TinyMCE editor while User 2 uses RokPad editor.

Is this possible?

I'm using Joomla 3.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes no problem at all. To do this:

- Go to to your Joomla! back-end,
- Install the editors you need via **Extensions** > **Manage** > **Install**,
- Then for each user you will have to set their editor. To do this go to:

  **Users** > **Manage**, from here select the user, click the "**Basic Settings**" Tab and select
   the editor in **Editor** field.
- Save and close.

Comment: Great! Completly overlooked that setting. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Great glad to be of help.

Comment: @Lynda, to extend Mike's answer, a user can also select on his own, his editor of choice, from his user profile settings.